# DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for XXX HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Tags: wordpress

**Error**
`DevTools failed to load SourceMap:`Could not load content for XXX  HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE`

How I can fix this error? This error prevents page to be secure.

[image]

Comment: Please provide some repro steps. What are you doing and why.

Comment: It seems that there is no style.css.map on you server. Does this tutorial help you:

https://medium.com/@toolmantim/getting-started-with-css-sourcemaps-and-in-browser-sass-editing-b4daab987fb0